# OpenGraph data won't show up on linkedin share

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, sharing

When sharing the URL on LinkedIn, the OpenGraph data won't show up. I did validate the data. Is this maybe a domain issue?

The url i tried to share was:
https://overons.kpn/en/news/2017/kpn-and-major-suppliers-aim-for-circular-operation-by-2025

edit: following error was thrown on just the domain: i18n_url_preview_error

Comment: did you solve the issue? i am experiencing the same.

Comment: @FinnFrotscher no, the only response i got was: The LinkedIn system does not recognize many of the new top level domains as being valid, as many of them have become a huge source of spamming and scamming.

Comment: that is invalid at least for me. we are on the german .de tld and for most articles there is no issue. just for some, seemingly without pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LinkedIn system does not recognize many of the new top level domains as being valid, as many of them have become a huge source of spamming and scamming.

Answer (score 0):

So LinkedIn share was working fine for me.
Today I started facing this error after moving on HTTPS.

Here is what I did :
While sharing URL, use http instead of https on LinkedIn and it will work (assuming that http redirects to https on your website).

I tried it for my site [CoverMyStartup](https://www.covermystartup.com) today. If this doesn't work, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine for me.  As usual, make sure you are URL-encoding your parameters...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.overons.kpn%2Fen%2Fnews%2F2017%2Fkpn-and-major-suppliers-aim-for-circular-operation-by-2025
```

See:

[image]

Maybe it was rejecting `.kpn` domains previously, but it seems to be good and working now!